# Multiple Pay Rates for Overtime

Tags: nested

I'm new to programming. I'm writing a payroll calculator program in visual studio and can't seem to get my second overtime rate to calculate correctly. I'm trying to accomplish the following:
Regular pay rate is multiplied by hours worked+holiday hours(typical 40hr week)
For hours worked in the range of 40-50 hours,regular pay rate*1.5(time & a half)
For hours worked in the range of 50-60 hours,regular pay rate*2(double time)

Here's the nested IFs that I'm having trouble with:

```
If HoursWorked >= 50 And HoursWorked < 61 And HolidayHours > 0 Then
        If HoursWorked >= 50 And HoursWorked < 61 Then
            DoublePay = (HoursWorked - 40) * RateofBasePay * 2
        ElseIf HoursWorked > 40 And HoursWorked < 50 Then
            TimeHalfPay = (HoursWorked - 40) * RateofBasePay * 1.5
        End If
        RegularPay = (HolidayHours + 40) * RateofBasePay
        GrossPay = RegularPay + DoublePay + TimeHalfPay

    ElseIf HoursWorked >= 50 And HoursWorked < 61 Then
        If HoursWorked >= 50 And HoursWorked < 61 Then
            DoublePay = (HoursWorked - 40) * RateofBasePay * 2
        ElseIf HoursWorked > 40 And HoursWorked < 50 Then
            TimeHalfPay = (HoursWorked - 40) * RateofBasePay * 1.5
        End If
        RegularPay = 40 * RateofBasePay
        GrossPay = DoublePay + TimeHalfPay + RegularPay
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question and fix the tags. This isn’t related to Visual Studio in any way and you haven’t tagged what language you’re using or what platform it’s on

Comment: The first line checks to ensure `50<=HoursWorked<61` , but inside that `if` statement you are checking if `40<HoursWorked<50` which is always false.  Same problem in the second stanza (`ElseIf`).  Further, based on your description, you don't want `else` statments.  You want to calculate 50<hrs<60 AND 40<hrs<50 AND hrs<40.

Comment: I see what you mean by this now. I updated my code to the following, but something is still not computing correctly. 

 DoublePay = (50 < HoursWorked < 61) * RateofBasePay * 2
 TimeHalfPay = (40 < HoursWorked < 50) * RateofBasePay * 1.5
 RegularPay = 40* RateofBasePay